# Replacement of using com.databricks.spark.avro.DirectAvroOutputCommitter in spark applications

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, avro

Project Details: Upgrading the spark versions and scala version as below
spark: 2.4.5 --> 3.2.0
scala: 2.11 --> 2.12

It sets hadoop configuration as below
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.avro.output.committer.class", "com.databricks.spark.avro.DirectAvroOutputCommitter").

After upgrading i am facing issues with above config.

Upgraded the library from "com.databricks" spark-avro to "org.apache.spark" spark-avro as databricks is outdated for spark 3.2.0.

Need help in replacement for setting the hadoop configuration as mentioned above.